# GetAccessToken in the ESB connector for toodledo API

Tags: xml, wso2, authorization, access-token, wso2-esb

I am implementing a connector for WSO2 ESB. As in the API document, we need to get access token and pass it to all other operations. 
To get the Access Token, we need to pass the username and password as Authorization header. I succeeded in doing this in REST client and also I can get the output when I hardcode my username and password.

Below is the endpoint and this header is generated by giving username and password. But we cannot pass these as URL parameters. When I tried with passing parameters, it gives me the message Authentication details not set in header or body.

Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0Mzo3RmpmcDBaQnIxS3REUmJuZlZkbUl3

https://api.toodledo.com/3/account/token.php

```
grant_type=authorization_code
code=49075c51ed30133f909f7c0dd03996e8f395be57
vers=3
os=7
device=iphone5s
```

Below is my code.

```
<parameter name="access_token" description="access Token for the Authorization." />
<sequence>
    <!-- Required parameters -->

    <parameter name="code" description="The authorization code that your got from the authorization step." />
    <parameter name="clientId" />
    <parameter name="secret" />

    <!-- Optional parameters -->
    <parameter name="vers"
               description="An integer representing the version number of your application.." />
    <parameter name="os"
               description="A text string identifying the device or platform that your application runs on." />
    <parameter name="device"
               description="An integer identifying the operating system version number of the device or platform that your application runs on." />



    <sequence>
        <header name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="transport" />

        <property expression="$func:clientId" name="toodleDo.clientId" type="STRING" />
        <property expression="$func:secret" name="toodleDo.secret" type="STRING" />

        <property name="temp" expression="fn:concat('<clientUsername>',':','<password>')" />
        <property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode(get-property('temp')))" scope="transport"  />

        <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" />
        <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />

        <property name="uri.var.code" expression="$func:code" />

        <filter xpath="(not(get-property('uri.var.vers') = ''))">
            <then>
                <property name="uri.var.vers" expression="$func:vers" />
            </then>
        </filter>
        <filter xpath="(not(get-property('uri.var.os') = ''))">
            <then>
                <property name="uri.var.os" expression="$func:os" />
            </then>
        </filter>
        <filter xpath="(not(get-property('uri.var.device') = ''))">
            <then>
                <property name="uri.var.device" expression="$func:device" />
            </then>
        </filter>


        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">

            <format>
                <xform>
                    <grant_type>authorization_code</grant_type>
                    <clientId>$1</clientId>
                    <secret>$2</secret>
                    <code>$3</code>
                    <vers>$4</vers>
                    <os>$5</os>
                    <device>$6</device>
                </xform>
            </format>

            <args>
                <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.clientId')" />
                <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.secret')" />
                <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.code')" />
                <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.vers')" />
                <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.os')" />
                <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.device')" />
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
```

This code works fine because Ii have hard coded the username and password. Is there any solution for this? How can I pass my username and password to these parameters without hard coding?

Comment: Can someone reply for this please?

Answer (score 0):

define uri.var.userName and uri.var.password as properties.

```
<property name="temp" expression="fn:concat( get-property('uri.var.userName'),':', get-property('uri.var.password'))" />
```